# Fallback Image with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

My uploader is working well apart from one small thing. The setting of default images. I'm using carrierwave for users to upload profile images of themselves:

*user model*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
    has_one :avatar, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: :user_id

    before_create :create_fallback_image

    def create_fallback_image
        self.create_avatar
    end
end
```

*image model*

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

    mount_uploader :file_name, AvatarUploader, auto_validate: false

    belongs_to :user
end
```

*avatar uploader*

```
class AvatarUploader < BaseUploader

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  process resize_to_fit: [75, 75]
  process convert: 'gif'

  def default_url
   'foobar'
  end

  def filename
      random_string + '.gif'
    end
  end

  def random_string
    @random_string ||= User.random_string
  end
end
```

When a user signs up without uploading an optional profile image, they are assigned an association to their profile image, but instead of the `default_url` working, they get a random string from the filename method.

I thought I could get around it like this:

*user model*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
    has_one :avatar, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: :user_id

    before_create :create_fallback_image

    def create_fallback_image
            # look here:

        self.create_avatar.create_fallback
    end
end
```

*image model*

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

    mount_uploader :file_name, AvatarUploader, auto_validate: false

    belongs_to :user

    def create_fallback
       self.update_attributes(file_name: 'my_fallback.jpg')
    end
end
```

and while it nearly, nearly works, when I update the attributes of the file_name column, the uploader kicks in and `my_fallback.jpg` is overridden by a random string from my `random_string` method!

Comment: As per the chat discussion, I have updated my answer with a helper method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Carrierwave` has a built-in fallback mechanism for default image

Update your `default_url` method in `AvatarUploader` as below:

```
  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "my_fallback.jpg"].compact.join('_'))
  end
```

where change `fallback/` to your desired folder path.
This way, when an `avatar` is not uploaded for a particular user then `my_fallback.jpg` would be used as fallback image.

Refer to section **[Providing a default URL](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url)** in Carrierwave Documentation.

> when I update the attributes of the file_name column, the uploader
>   kicks in and my_fallback.jpg is overridden by a random string from my
>   random_string method!

This happens because you have overridden `filename` method in `AvatarUploader` which gets called every time an image is uploaded. If you notice, its calling `random_string` method in it. Hence, you get a `random string` as your filename.

**UPDATE**

As per the chat session with OP, if an avatar is not uploaded for a user then a default image should be shown. I suggested the following helper :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def display_avatar(user)  
    unless user.avatar.nil? 
      image_tag(user.avatar.file_name) 
    else
      image_tag("/path/to/fallback.jpg")
     end    
  end
  ## ...
end
```

Use this helper method in views to display avatar image appropriately.

Comment: So this should work, even though `default_url` wasn't returning `"foobar"`?

Comment: What I mean is that you should be using the available fallback mechanism rather than create a new one. In your case `default_url` would not be called as you are manually updating the `file_name` with a random string. `default_url` would come in picture when there `file_name` is not set,i.e., its nil.

Comment: I replaced my default_url with the helper you gave me but I'm still getting the random string via my `file_name` method. It's because a new avatar is being created in the database, and carrierwave thinks an new image must have been uploaded as well I guess... I think the culprit here is my `self.create_avatar` call in the model, but what else can I do? A user needs an avatar, even if it's the fallback. Otherwise I can't run `<%= image_tag user.avatar.file_name %>` in a view...

Comment: Bottomline is that you don't need to update the records which don't have any images. As it would be taken care by the default_url.

Comment: Okay.. but how should I run `<%= image_tag user.avatar.file_name %>` in a view if some users don't have an avatar? Create a virtual attribute in the user model?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do it within model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :avatar, class_name: 'User::Avatar', as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar, allow_destroy: true #, ...

  def avatar
    super || build_avatar
  end
end
```